# Jmeter - mark the test as failed based on response data

Tags: jmeter

I have written a jmeter test script which automates booking in of cases by sends http post requests to our web application.

At the moment as long as you get a response back from the server it's successfull.

Is there a way it can pass the test only when the response  doesn't contain the message error has occured and contains a booking reference

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? if ok it should be accepted and upvoted. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion)

To test that response does not contain Error message check the "Not":
[image]

See also:

- https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/what-are-my-options-for-using-assertions-in-jmeter/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Assertions for this.
With this u can lookup the response body, the response code...
Look at this tutorial: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps

You can stop the test if one assertion fails in the thread group (I think).